# Trying to create staff schedule in Sharepoint online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

The attached image will hopefully illustrate what I am trying to accomplish in SharePoint 2013.  I am pretty new to SharePoint, but I think what I 'may' need to figure out is how to tie a master list (of employees) to a weekly view (not sure if I have to somehow associate the list of employees with a calendar or not?).

I don't necessarily need all of the features I have explained in the attached illustration, but if I could at least get a set grid/list of employees to display based on the full work week we are currently and with the ability to look at past and future  weeks...that would be great.  Plus it is ok if the scheduling managers are able to schedule for all staff, as we are a small group and we are pretty trust worthy.  So, in other words, I don't necessarily need to limit the editable grid to staff under specific manager oversight. Also, the day cells are simply text entries, they are not associated with any type of pre-set/defined shift.

Can anyone help with this?  We are even willing to pay for consulting services, if need be.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered Project Online? It has the resource calendar, where you can configure working time, and time off as exceptions. You can have a corporate holiday calendar that applies to your resources, and if you start controlling your tasks in projects, you also start having resource availability reports....

Comment: you can also assign resources to managers, and only those managers are allowed to change the resource's working times, so you also get a nice security set up behind it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved through a custom Visual Studio web part solution using SharePoint lists as data sources that can be edited by end users.

Others can feel free to correct me, but the level of customization you require here puts this beyond the OOB capabilities of SharePoint/SPD.